# How do I get a Dart test to load the main file?

Tags: dart

I have a Dart project which I set up using the project creation tool `dart create myproject`.

I have a main file 'bin/myproject.dart'.

I'm now following documentation on how to write tests.

But https://dart.dev/guides/testing doesn't explain how to actually write the tests. All I've managed to find is https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction

That says I do this to import the project's main file:

```
import 'package:counter_app/counter.dart';
```

but I've tried this:

```
import 'package:myproject/myproject.dart';
```

and that fails because that looks in /lib not /bin.

How do I include the main file from the test file?

Comment: You can try to read docs and use samples from [test](https://pub.dev/packages/test) plugin.

Comment: I can't see any example on that page of import statements loading from the current project.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've figured it out. `dart create` created a command-line project, with a file in /bin.

`import 'package:myproject/myproject.dart';` imports files in /lib, so the thing to do was to move most code into /lib, and then both the test and the command do `import 'package:myproject/myproject.dart';`.